# Is there any way to check the presence of a registry value directly using RegGetValue()?

Tags: c++, windows, registry

> Is there any way to check the presence of a registry value directly using `RegGetValue()`?

The docs for `RegGetValue()` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/da-dk/library/windows/desktop/ms724868(v=vs.85).aspx) doesn't mention what happens in case the value is missing.

Does a type of `REG_NONE` (*No defined value type*) indicate that the value is missing, or does it only tell that the value has an unspecified type?

Is the only option to call `RegEnumValue()` and check the name of each value?

Thanks...

Comment: MSDN says "If the function fails, the return value is a system error code." and the code would be `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` or similar.

Comment: But there are more than 1000 codes. Should one just guess and hope for the best?

Comment: Call a working implementation of RegGetValue() with a key name that does not exist, thats the error code to use.

Comment: Thank you. It would just be nice if I could find this information on my own - do you know it through experiments?

Comment: You don't need to guess. In most cases you compare to success code only. At some rare times you can also compare to certain specific error codes you want to handle separately (e.g. "access denied").

Comment: In this case, I want to check if a value is present before writing to it, i.e. I don't want to overwrite it.

Answer (score 2):

As [Roman R.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35915092/is-there-any-way-to-check-the-presence-of-a-registry-value-directly-using-regget#comment59488976_35915092) stated in a comment, you need to check the function's return value.
In your case it will be something like this:

```
DWORD dwErrorResult = RegGetValue(...);
switch(dwErrorResult)
{
case ERROR_SUCCESS:
    // Success -> means that the value is found and data is read
    break;
case ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND:
    // Value not found - you should do your thing here
    break;
case ERROR_MORE_DATA:
    // The buffer is too small to hold the value
    break;
case ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER:
    // An invalid combination of flags was specified
    break;
default:
    // An unknown error occurred.
    break;
}
```